# We have a ternary predicate Procurement(Supplier, Component, Project)

Tags: machine-learning, semantics

We have a ternary predicate Procurement(Supplier, Component, Project). Also, we have three binary Predicates as follows:

Supplies_supplies_Component(Supplier, Component)
Component_used_in_Project(Component, Project)
Supplier_involved_in_Project(Supplier, Project).

For a particular set of Supplier=S1, Component = C1 and Project = P1 (more than one options may be correct)

1. If all three binary predicates are true, the ternary predicate is also true
2. If the ternary predicate is true, then all the three binary predicates are true
3. If all three binary predicates are true, the ternary predicate may or may not be true
4. If the ternary predicate is true, then all the three binary predicates may or may not be true

I came with this question in my syllabus. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the ternary predicate is true, then all the three binary predicates are true
2. If all three binary predicates are true, the ternary predicate may
   or may not be true

Answer (score 0):

It should be actually -

2. If the ternary predicate is true, then all the three binary predicates are true
3. If all three binary predicates are true, the ternary predicate may or may not be true

because the following predicates if true,

- Supplies_supplies_Component(Supplier, Component) -- may not be used in the same project
- Component_used_in_Project(Component, Project) -- may not be supplied by the same supplier
- Supplier_involved_in_Project(Supplier, Project) -- but the component supplied may not be used in the same project instance

So by this logic, option 1 proves to be not true.

Answer (score -2):

If the ternary predicate is true, then all the three binary predicates are true
If all three binary predicates are true, the ternary predicate may or may not be true